# Merging Two DKIM Records

Tags: email, dkim

How can I merge two dkim records? One is Google Dkim signature and the other is Send Grid Dkim Signature.

**Google Dkim:**

```
TXT record name - google._domainkey
TXT record value - v=DKIM1;
k=rsa;     p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDDsE5DxlET/ICDhTa6jv1b1Hv3zuTVxGUzX20hX/xkaJag0R7qDZrt1TFyMDWk2w0jvmmx3NNM1nkX8Q4OW5KoUMxAlYvckNC6R3Juk+gqfs7PFshdgItEbAHQly0t9pzUcycNZBAHcG0R557SJvvOjd5dXwrQ/HYsivTaOk32yQIDAQAB
```

**Send Grid:**

```
TXT Name: smtpapi._domainkey.yourdomain.com
TXT value: k=rsa;
t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDPtW5iwpXVPiH5FzJ7Nrl8USzuY9zqqzjE0D1r04xDN6qwziDnmgcFNNfMewVKN2D1O+2J9N14hRprzByFwfQW76yojh54Xu3uSbQ3JP0A7k8o8GutRF8zbFUA8n0ZH2y0cIEjMliXY4W4LwPA7m4q0ObmvSjhd63O9d8z1XkUBwIDAQAB
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you can't. If an email is being sent through GMAIL, then GMAIL is going to DKIM sign it, if you're mailing through Send Grid, then they are going to sign it.

Both Gmail and Send grid is going to sign it with the private keys (They will be different). So you can't have a common public key.

But I would like to know why you want to do this? Maybe their is a different solution to your issue?

Comment: I am using GSuite as my mailing solution and send grid for my marketing. Since the I haven't added the DKIM signature few mails being sent from SendGrid are not reaching my customer.

Comment: When i checking for a suggestion i got to know if DKIM and DMARC records are added this will be sorted. I already have my GSuite DKIM and wanted to merge both the records

Comment: You can't merge DKIM, I think in SendGrid you can set it up to use a custom domain to sign with. But I doubt, GSuite is going to share the private key with you. But I really doubt, this is causing the non-delivery issue. I think, it would have to do more with the IP Reputation that SendGrid is using and that IP possibly being blocked at your customers spam filter.